# display longer product name in 2 lines in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, css, name

please visit this link :

on bottom you can see " Latest Product Added " under that first product is

"longer product name need to display in 2 lines "

as like in products list page, how to display above product name in 2 lines.

product_bestseller_block.phtml = >

please help me to find solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not exactly a magento question... the easiest solution is to add fixed width to .best-sell-product

```
.best-sell-product {width: 150px;}
```

the rule can be found in http://kidsdial.com/skin/frontend/default/default/marketplace/css/wk_block.css line 95.

If css is not an option, you can split the name using PHP, inserting a `<br>` after N chars (use strlen, preg_split, explode, substr)

Comment: I used php string functions. 

Thanks a lot for your help